# Retrieve license key from Windows 8 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-8, license, license-key

Is there a way to retrieve the License Key from a Win 8 Enterprise machine? We had another tech install Win 8 on an SOHO computer and didn't leave a license key. Trying to get ahold of it for recordkeeping. Magic Jellybean didn't work as it's Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

When you use KMS, you only have a generic VL client key (GVLK) on your PC.

In the future, use the [Volume Activation Management Tool (VAMT)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824953.aspx) to manage all your keys to avoid such key hassles.

Comment: That didn't tell me how to retrieve it. :-/

Comment: use the generic keys from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612867.aspx